# Changing text size of go Treemap for text inside sectors

Tags: treemap

I have been looking to increase to the size of the text contained in a graph object Treemap, but with no success. I tried inserting HTML line breaks in the actual text but that didn't work. Maybe I am missing a simple solution. The docs have textinfo, textposition but not text size. Here is what it currently looks like: I just want the text to be readable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgKqy.png)

Thank for you help!

EDIT: Here is my current code:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
ids=df_treemap['id'].tolist(),
labels=df_treemap['labels'].tolist(),
parents=df_treemap['parent'].tolist(),
values=df_treemap['value'].tolist(),
branchvalues='total',
hovertemplate='<b>%{label}',
insidetextfont=dict(size=11),
textfont=dict(size=30),
marker=dict(
    colors=df_treemap['color'],
    colorscale='RdBu',
    cmid=1,
    showscale=True),
name='',
text=summaries,
```

I have tried cutting the text up with the following, but that does help:
short_summaries = [textwrap.fill(df['Summary'].tolist()[0],10) if
isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame) else 'N.A' for df in x]

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the [official docs](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Treemap.html):

> textfont – Sets the font used for textinfo.

And it has a `size` property.

Comment: Thanks navylover, but that does not change anything (for some reason).